# VS 2012 TFS stuck on loading identity providers

Tags: c#, tfs

vs2012 TFS gets stuck on loading identity providers. The server is ok the credentials are fine.Any suggestions what is the main problem

Comment: which version of tfs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have network problem, your client can't connect to your domain controller, ensure that your VPN is correct, and you can ping your host of active directory

Comment: Happy for solving and help you Muneeb

Comment: I'm having the same issue, was it the time zone that you changed to get it working?

Comment: This also fixed an issue I had signing in to VS2013.